# How to make an incomplete page loading checker

Tags: php, javascript, html

So I already asked the question in the title .
what I want to do is similar to what facebook mobile site (iPhone version) does .
if there's A SLOW internet connection , it shows you a message : Can't load page ! or something like that .
how can this be done in js (or) php ?
I tried onerror"myfunction()" attribute in HTML but it didn't work :/

Comment: ... think about this for a moment.  If there's no Internet connection, how exactly to you expect your JavaScript code to get to the client in order to show a message?

Comment: No no , it's just an example . what if there was a slow connection and the data aren't fully loaded ?

Comment: What I'd try to do is have a javascript variable set at the beginning of the page, and then when the client loads the last line, set that variable equal to `YES` or `1`. Back at the top, I'd have a function run via `setTimeout` to check that variable after a specified amount of time. If the variable has been set (complete page loaded) then show the data. If it hasn't been set (not loaded completely) then show an error. I won't post this as an answer, though, as I haven't ever tried it myself and it may not apply to you in your situation.

Comment: it doesn't help because even if the  page isn't completly loaded the onload() function will run normally , thanks for you suggestion tho

Answer (score 1):

use js.
in top of page(i.e:very after  tag),add js like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loaded=0;
    setTimeout('if(!loaded){alert('you have not laoded!');}',5000/*5000ms*/);
</script>
```

and in the bottom of page(i.e:very before  tag), add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loaded=1;
</script>
```

Comment: @Ray I just fixed his formatting, at the very list that code needs different type of quotation marks.